# Why does BigQuery return a blank column in a query joining two sample GitHub tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using this SQL code to join across two tables. My goal is to get the repo_name, the contents and the path when the content starts with the string "import". But the last column is empty. Is this an error in my query, or is this a bug in BigQuery?

```
SELECT
  contents.id,
  files.repo_name
  files.path,
  contents.content
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents] as contents
  JOIN [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_files] as files
ON files.id = contents.id
WHERE
REGEXP_MATCH (contents.content, r'^import')
LIMIT
  100;
```

(I'm assuming the commit hash is the ID in both of the tables. This is not documented, but it seems to return data.)

The result is this:

```
Row | contents_id | files_path | contents_content | <blank>
1     33249e...     jbandu..     import Ember...    <blank>
2     53d65e...     pubpub...    import React...    <blank>
...more lines...
```

Where I've noted blank the column is not labeled. And, there is no data there. It seems like the query is starting with the wrong 2nd column; shouldn't it be `files_repo_name`? I've verified my select statement is correct in using the right names from each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a blank cell if I scroll all the way to the right of the query results, but it doesn't represent a column. The JSON representation of the response does not contain an extra column either. If you run a query such as `SELECT 1 AS x;`, the result will have a single column with a blank placeholder to the right of it.

One weird thing with the query above is that it aliases `files.repo_name` as `files.path`, since there is no comma after `files.repo_name`. I normally use standard SQL in BigQuery, and you can express the same query in this form:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  id,
  files.repo_name,
  files.path,
  contents.content
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_contents` as contents
  JOIN `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_files` as files
USING (id)
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS (contents.content, r'^import')
LIMIT
  100;
```

Comment: Right, I must have left off the comma. Strange the validation didn't flag that.

Comment: Legacy SQL supports multi-part column aliases, so the query is valid. Did this answer your question, though? If so, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @xrd validation was correct because it treated `files.path` as alias for `files.repo_name`